# Scala - Initiating a trait?

Tags: scala, traits

There is this code:

```
// Initial object algebra interface for expressions: integers and addition
trait ExpAlg[E] {
    def lit(x : Int) : E 
    def add(e1 : E, e2 : E) : E
}

// An object algebra implementing that interface (evaluation)

// The evaluation interface
trait Eval {
    def eval() : Int
}

// The object algebra
trait EvalExpAlg extends ExpAlg[Eval] {
    def lit(x : Int) = new Eval() {
        def eval() = x
    }

    def add(e1 : Eval, e2 : Eval) = new Eval() {
        def eval() = e1.eval() + e2.eval()
    }
}
```

I really would like to know why it is allowed to initiate the `trait Eval` type with `new Eval()` like being a class?

Comment: You can do the same thing with Interfaces in Java. Like Ende answered below, this internally defines an anonymous class implementing the Interface in case of Java and similarly the trait in case of Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are instantiating an anonymous class, that is a class which doesn't have a name:

```
trait ExpAlg[E] {
  def lit(x : Int) : E
  def add(e1 : E, e2 : E) : E
}

trait Eval {
  def eval() : Int
}

val firstEval = new Eval {
  override def eval(): Int = 1
}

val secondEval = new Eval {
  override def eval(): Int = 2
}
```

now you have two anonymous classes and each has a different implementation for the `eval` method, note that being anonymous means that you can't instantiate a new `firstEval` or `secondEval`. In your specific case you have a method that always returns an anonymous class with the same implementation of that `eval` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explenation. I really didn't know that. For me it wasn't anonymous until it use the name of the trait and looks like it is a true instance of that trait. That was my confusion.