# Scala object and trait having same name

Tags: scala, object, traits

In Scala, a class and an object can be companion(same name, same file)

I came across Scala source code, with a file having a trait and object defined in it and both having same name, but object is not extending trait.

Is this style ok?

Comment: I got answer here:https://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/selfless_trait_pattern.html

Comment: "but object is not extending trait" Companion objects _can_ extend the trait/class they are companions for, but that's quite rare.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, In both the case trait or object same name object become a companion object you can see below code you can access private members in class and trait both situations

trait

```
trait Simple {
private def line = "Line"
}

object Simple {
val objTrait = new Simple{}
def lineObj=objTrait.line
}

Simple.lineObj
```

class

```
class Simple {
private def line = "Line"
}

object Simple {
val objTrait = new Simple{}
def lineObj=objTrait.line
}

Simple.lineObj
```

Comment: Can trait be instantiated?

Comment: Yes you can by new trait_name {} define unimplemented members inside the braces

Comment: reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191975/scala-initiating-a-trait?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

A typical use case for `object` is for methods and fields that you would mark as `static` in Java, if that helps.

The `object` doesn't extend the `trait` / `class`, it accompanies it, hence the term *companion object*.